# Building eclipselink-2.6.0 fails with Missing requirement

Tags: java, maven, ant, osgi, eclipselink

1. Downloaded source code from github (https://codeload.github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/tar.gz/2.6.0) and extracted to eclipselink-2.6.0
2. Downloaded and configured ant 1.10.6 (ANT_HOME+PATH) and maven 3.0.5 (M2_HOME+PATH)
3. Started the build in directory eclipselink-2.6.0 with the command
   ant -f antbuild.xml

The build fails with:

```sh
[java] [INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.sdo:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/xix/Projects/eclipselink-2.6.0/sdo/org.eclipse.persistence.sdo/pom.xml
     [java] [INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.sdo:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/xix/Projects/eclipselink-2.6.0/sdo/org.eclipse.persistence.sdo/pom.xml
     [java] [INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
     [java] [INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
     [java] [INFO] {osgi.os=linux, osgi.ws=gtk, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}
     [java] [ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
     [java] [ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.persistence.sdo 2.6.0.qualifier
     [java] [ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.persistence.sdo 2.6.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.persistence.asm [5.0.1,5.0.2)' but it could not be found
     [java] [ERROR] 
     [java] [ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.persistence.sdo 2.6.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.persistence.asm [5.0.1,5.0.2).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.] -> [Help 1]
     [java] org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.persistence.sdo 2.6.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.persistence.asm [5.0.1,5.0.2).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
     [java]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
     [java]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
     [java]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
     [java]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.persistence.sdo 2.6.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.persistence.asm [5.0.1,5.0.2).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:166)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:103)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:352)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:325)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:107)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
     [java]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
     [java]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
     [java]     ... 11 more
     [java] [ERROR] 
     [java] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
     [java] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
     [java] [ERROR] 
     [java] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
     [java] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build eclipselink, download from the following link from github.

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/archive/master.zip

After downloading, run the ant command as `ant -f antbuild.xml`

Comment: Master runs w/o problems, but I need 2.6.0, which is bundled with payara-4.1.2.182, to check some strange behaviour. And idea how to get 2.6.0 building?

Comment: SOLUTION in my case is:
correct eclipselink-2.6.0/sdo/org.eclipse.persistence.sdo/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
from: org.eclipse.persistence.asm;bundle-version="[5.0.1,5.0.2)"
to: org.eclipse.persistence.asm;bundle-version="5.0.1"

Comment: In this older version, is there any documentation about how to build ?

Comment: There is a common [guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Building). There seems to be a bug in maven, so i went back to 3.0.5, I also don't run tests since it only for some experiments. Basically I run:

```
  M2_HOME="/home/vagrant/Apps/apache-maven-3.0.5"
  PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"

  ANT_HOME=/home/vagrant/Apps/apache-ant-1.10.6
  PATH="$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH"
  ant build-eclipselink-jar -f antbuild.xml
```